# Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which has been running for about 1 year.

We have always been able to connect via SSH without issue until yesterday, when suddenly after a reboot all my connections are refused.

I have never made any modifications to the ssh config.
I have setup the EC2 security group to allow SSH on port 22 from 0.0.0.0/0 to ensure that changing IPs can't be an issue.

When I try connecting with SSH through PuTTY -

> Network error - connection refused.

When I try connecting SSH through AWS console -

> There was a problem setting up the instance connection
>   An error occurred and we were unable to connect or stay connected to your instance. If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.

Tried restart, stop, force stop and start again. Issue persists across boots, and even when volume is attached to a new instance as root volume.

The System log in AWS console shows:

> Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
>   See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.

`[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
See 'systemctl status ssh.service' for details.`

The problem is that I can't connect to run commands and check the ssh.service status.

I have cloned the volume and attached to a new instance as secondary drive.

I have checked sshd.conf file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and can't see any corruption.
I have also checked the auth.log file and can see many CRON activity, but nothing from SSHD:

```
Nov 26 10:39:08 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1163]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Nov 26 10:39:08 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1163]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Nov 26 10:39:08 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1163]: New seat seat0.
Nov 26 10:40:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[2089]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:41:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[2774]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:41:03 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[2089]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:42:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[3410]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:42:02 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[2774]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:43:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[4042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:43:02 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[3410]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:44:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[4660]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:44:02 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[4042]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:45:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[5290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:45:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[4660]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:46:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[5912]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 10:46:02 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[5290]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Nov 26 10:46:46 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1166]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Nov 26 10:46:46 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1166]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Sleep Button)
Nov 26 10:46:46 ip-172-31-9-### systemd-logind[1166]: New seat seat0.
Nov 26 10:47:01 ip-172-31-9-### CRON[1775]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
```

Looking back at when it was working, I can see lines like this:

```
Nov 26 01:53:50 ip-172-31-14-### sshd[6236]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 58.96.###.### port 50753 ssh2: RSA SHA256:#######################
Nov 26 01:53:50 ip-172-31-14-### sshd[6236]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Nov 26 01:53:50 ip-172-31-14-### systemd-logind[1128]: New session 20 of user ubuntu.
```

This is on a production instance. I have managed to revert to a backup and launch on a new instance.
That is working for now, but really need to get to the root cause of this issue to ensure that we aren't stuck unable to connect again.

Any idea what the issue could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know I'm having this same exact issue. Must have happened about the same time because last time I logged in was Nov. 25th, tried it just this morning and all my connections are being refused. What's weird is it didn't happen on the other Ubuntu instance we have running, and this one was powered off over the holiday.

Comment: @user384625

Strange. I have managed to get ssh working again after many restarts. Now I am afraid it might happen again if I reboot .